# Tensorflow async / concurrent for loop

Tags: tensorflow, asynchronous, keras

I'm curious if there's a way to process items asynchronously in a for loop if I'm using the same instance of a model.

Right now I'm just iterating over each item, processing it synchronously, and moving onto the next (but each takes awhile):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

from models import Model1, Model2, Model3
from utils import utils

model1 = Model1()
model2 = Model2()
model3 = Model3()

def start():
    # some non-tensorflow stuff

    for image_path in image_paths:
        # extract images from original
        image1, image2, image3 = utils.process(image_path, model2, model3)

        # create a new image
        inference = model1.inference(image1, image2, image3)
        image4 = np.squeeze(((inference[0] + 1) * 255 / 2).astype(np.uint8))
        result_image = utils.post_process(image_path, model2, image4, image1, image2)

        # overwrite the existing image
        Image.fromarray(result_image).save(image_path)

    # do some other non-tensorflow stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

Any insight is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is "item" here? An image or text input?

Comment: Hi Risbabh — it’s an image!

Answer (score 0):

Nearly every model will run faster it you batch your images and pack a bunch into each call. That's the cleanest way to gain some performance in this case. Any reason not to?

I'm not sure what's in your tensorflow model, but AFAIK modern TensorFlow does asynchronopus dispatch by default, the eager-tensors you get back are handles to future results. It blocks and waits for a result when you pull the value out in the `#do something with the result` portion.

Sure, you could do something like: put the loading, inferring, and `do smething` parts each in their own thread (or process) with multithread (multiprocessing)  queues in between. That way your loading and `Do something` run in parallel with the inference. But that feels like we're reinventing the deprecated "tensorflow input queues". These threads still fight over the GIL, and stuff like that.

So maybe a better approach, if batching doesn't do enough for you, is to run this using `tf.data`:

```
filenames = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(...)
results = filenames.map(load_and_infer_image, 
                       num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
results = results.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
for result in result:
  # do something.
```

The `prefetch` method allows the dataset to run in the background, prefetching those inference results while you do stuff in the python loop.

If there's stuff you can't or don't feel like expressing in pure-tensorflow you can either wrap them with [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) or [`tf.py_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function)

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you @mdaoust. I'm admittedly a complete TensorFlow novice though and am running into complications attempting to use this implementation and was wondering if you could shed a little extra light on it for me. I'm going to edit my original question to add some more details. Thanks in advance!